# Pure REST or process driven design in a "wizard" account creation process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rest

I'm in the process of building an app that has a bit of a lengthy sign up wizard.

The wizard will have these steps (with associated model class(es)):

1. Organization Information (Organization)
2. Account Plan (OrganizationSubscription, OrganizationSubscriptionType)
3. Payment Details (OrganizationPaymentDetail)
4. User Account (AdminUser)

Do you recommend building a wizard controller i.e. "AccountSetup" that houses the creation of all of these objects through each step, OR should I go the purely RESTful way that creates these objects only in their associated resource path and action. This controller would only be used once per Organization setup. Any edits or additional account information would use only RESTful resources.

Obviously the former would be easier given that I need to visually display the step to the user and show views with validation errors without having to do a bunch of redirects and storing state in the session.

However, the latter would be more of a best practice. I want to build so any developer can dig in.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to push the wizard into the database so you can more easily keep track of incomplete signups and stuff. So you could have a wizard model that has a state and that belongs_to all the relevant associated models that you create from the wizard (incidentally you also don't litter your controller code with this logic but rather push it back into the model).

Also this provides you with one point where you can validate that all associated models are correct and ready to be finished.